# Three.js complex material with displacement

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am wondering if there is a way to combine two normal maps at runtime in javascript/threejs. My problem is. I have a lot of cube like models, each of them is made from:

- the box like mesh
- a front face that hide the inside of the box

All box-like meshes use MeshStandartMaterial and they all have normal maps applied to them. 
Plane-like meshes (fronts) all have displacement and normal maps applied to them. I use normal map (with front) to make displacement look more defined.

The problem is I need to apply to front the "material" normal map as well, so I am looking for the way to combine it with displacement normal map.

Is it possible to combine them using canvas 2d context?

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/e6rbt3r4/) is an example that combines 2 images for use as a map

Comment: I have tried to use canvas content as a map for meshStandardMaterial and shader doesn't compile now.

Comment: ok, it was my bug, I have made some modification to threejs

Comment: As your 'answer' is likely going to be deleted, it may be useful to point out that you can see (and salvage) your deleted post through https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/3635666